# Immediately stop a setTimeout loop without finishing current cycle

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Im creating a user operated random selector. Users hit a button and the system selects two random results (which will be videos).

The page will then alternately highlight two random results - they user can hit the button again and they can choose the video they want.

Its all working quite nicely, but the alternating highlighting is done with a setTimeout loop which finishes its current cycle, rather than stopping immediately.

how would I get it so that when the user presses the 'select' button the flit function stops immediately - not when the current loop is over?

Here's the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/zandergrin/tmwst5z9/4/

ps - apologies, but this is a work in progrees - I know there's a few messy bits in here...
    var interval = 0;

```
function random() {
    // create the array
    var posts = ["post 1", "post 2", "post 3", "post 4", "post 5", "post 6", "post 7", "post 8", "post 9", "post 10"];
    var results = posts

    // Shuffle array
    .sort(function () {
        return .5 - Math.random()
    })

    // Get first 2 items
    .slice(0, 2);
    var post1 = results[0];
    var post2 = results[1];

    // add them to the DOM
    $('#res1').html(post1);
    $('#res2').html(post2);

    // loop it
    interval = setTimeout(random, 100);

}

function start() {
    // Hide the start button
    $("#start").css("display", "none");
    $("#stop").css("display", "block");
    // Start the randomizer
    random();

}


function stop() {
    // Hide the stop button and stop the random() timeout
    clearTimeout(interval);
    $("#stop").css("display", "none");
    $("#select").css("display", "block");

    // set the inital background colour
    $("#res1").css({'background': '#123','color': '#fff'});
    $("#res2").css({'background': '#eee','color': '#000'});

    //create a function to flick between items
    function flit() {
        //color the results
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#res1").css({'background': '#eee','color': '#000'});
            $("#res2").css({'background': '#123','color': '#fff'});
        }, 800);

        //colour again after a delay
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#res1").css({'background': '#123','color': '#fff'});
            $("#res2").css({'background': '#eee','color': '#000'});
        }, 1600);

        //loop it
        timer = setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1600);
    };
    //run the flick function
    flit();

}


function select() {
    // stop thie flit function - doesnt stop immediately!
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $("#select").css("display","none");
    $("#refresh").css("display", "block");
}

function refresh() {
    location.reload();
}
```

Comment: Just a tip: sorting by `.5 - Math.random()` isn't the best way to shuffle an array because it allows `a>b && b>c && c>a` to be true, which can confuse the `sort` implementation badly. A simple shuffle is `.map(function(x){return [Math.Random(),x]; }).sort(function(a,b){return a[0]-b[0];}).map(function(x){ return x[1];})`. For more efficiency, google the Knuth Fisher-Yates shuffle.

Comment: Thanks for that - I had read about the Knuth Fisher-Yates shuffle. I understood the reasoning but most of the implementations I googled went a little over my head if I'm honest!. Using that now...

Comment: Just to be clear, that code isn't Knuth-Fisher-Yates, it's just a safe, unbiased shuffle, but it's not as efficient as KFY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in the `flit()` function - you need to assign references to the `setTimeout` calls so you can call `clearTimeout` on them. Right now, you're stopping `flit()` from being called in the `select()` method, but the two timers are still queued to execute in the future.

Comment: Of course! Overlooked that - thanks. here's teh working fiddle for those interested http://jsfiddle.net/zandergrin/tmwst5z9/6/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @sholanozie answer, I would recommend placing those setTimeout's in a array(ie `arrayOfTimeouts`), and then:

```
function select() {
    // stop thie flit function - doesnt stop immediately!
    arrayOfTimeouts.forEach(function(setTimer) {
        clearTimeout(setTimer);
});
```

Comment: This didn't work for me unfortunately. Thanks though.